why is my fine tuned model being saved as a safetensors file?
since im fairly new to this im trying to understand things slowly but this one thing has confused me a lot, is there a way to save the file to .h5 format or to convert it to tflite ? is the model good for mobile applications ? i havent figured it out ,and i really don't know what to do with this safetensor file that seems to only hold the model and no weights
i have fine tuned a vit model on a dataset so i wanted to save it, which i did using trainer.save_model(model_dir)
i am using this particular model from huggingface
model = ViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k', num_labels=num_classes)

feature_extractor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')

now im left with a safetensor format
